# What is error with this code?

Tags: c

The executable file suddenly stopped working. The whole lot works but the part of reversal of linked list makes the exe file to do so.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
} *start=NULL;

main()
{
    int i=1,n,data;
    printf("\nEnter the number of nodes you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter the key no. 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    struct node *p=start,*tmp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp->info=data;
    tmp->link=NULL;
    start=tmp;
    while(i<n)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the key no. %d: ",(i+1));
        scanf("%d",&data);
        while(p!=NULL)
                p=p->link;
            tmp->info=data;
        tmp->link=NULL;
        p=tmp;
        i++;
    }
    p=start;
    printf("\nThe list is: ");
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",p->info);
        p=p->link;
    }
    p=start;
    printf("\nThe reversed list is: ");
    while(p->link->link!=NULL)
    {
        p->link->link=p;
        p=p->link;
    }
    start->link=NULL;
    start=p->link;
    for(p=start;p!=NULL;p=p->link)
        printf("%d",p->info);
    getch();
    return 0; //main shourl return.
}
```

Comment: What the heck are you asking, "makes the exe file to do so?"  Your question title mentions an error code, yet you show no error.  Please read on how to post a proper question.

Answer (score 1):

you have : `*p=start` , `start=NULL`, and then `while(p!=NULL) p=p->link;`.

Never gonna happen, since `p` is null :)

Answer (score 0):

Your program is quite error prone
initially `start==NULL`

and statement 1

`struct node *p=start,*tmp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`
this will make **p is equal to NULL**

then statement 2:

```
start=tmp;
```

this will update **start** but will not update **p**

You should break the statement 1

```
struct node *tmp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
//processing tmp
struct node *p=start=tmp
```

Also

`//at time of insertion`

```
   while(p!=NULL)
      p=p->link;
    tmp->info=data;
    tmp->link=NULL;
    p=tmp;
```

watch **while loop** clearly, **p** will *come out of loop* when it is **NULL** , then your are adding to `p=tmp` (assign tmp to null) **which is illegal**.

you should this to

```
while(p->link!=NULL)
   p=p->link;
tmp->info=data;
tmp->link=NULL;
p->link=tmp;
```